# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'. Getting this error for component with Angular 6 CLI

Tags: angular

Im using Angular 6 with CLI, Im getting the error as follows while building the application.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP631.png) 
while the same code was working earlier, and for all the other components im not getting this error though they use the same code

I'm not using webpack.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ScenariosService } from "./scenarios.service";
import { GridDataResult, DataStateChangeEvent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-grid";
import { State } from "@progress/kendo-data-query";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { SolutionsService } from "../solutions/solutions.service";
import { CookieService } from "ngx-cookie-service";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {IScenarioList} from './IscenarioList';


@Component({
    selector: "app-scenarios",
    templateUrl: "./scenarios.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./scenarios.component.css"]
})
export class ScenariosComponent implements OnInit {

    scenarios: any = [];
    public gridData: GridDataResult;
    public pageSize = 100;
    public skip = 0;
    public state: State = {
        skip: 0,
        take: 20
    };
    public view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
    solsdata: string;
    private editedRowIndex: number;
    public formGroup: FormGroup;


    constructor(private scenarioservice: ScenariosService, private solutionservice: SolutionsService, private cookieservice: CookieService) { }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.view = this.scenarioservice;
        this.solsdata = this.cookieservice.get("SolutionId");
        this.scenarioservice.query(this.state, this.solsdata);      
     }          
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you missing some file and closing brackets

Comment: can you share your code properly

Comment: Hello I have added components code here, and Error as well. This component was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created a separate component and pasted all the code in the new component and it worked there. Couldn't find the actual cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments said, you are missing the closing } bracket.

It should be:
`@Component({
        selector: "app-sln",
        templateUrl: "./sln.component.html"})`